# Integral with unreliable result

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate
$\int_R^1 \sqrt{r} |\cos((k+\frac{1}{2})\pi r)|dr $
and I get a result from Mathematica.
Then I try to check the result putting the value of $k$ and $R$, (k=1 and R=0.5) in the result and performing a NIntegrate with the same value and the result is different.
In the analytical result if you put $k=10$ and $R=0.5$ the result is negative and of course wrong, but if I use Nintegrate the result is posivite.
What happened?
I am interested in the following function of $R$ and $k$.

$$\text{Assuming}\left[R>0\textrm{&&}k>1\textrm{&&}R<1\textrm{&&}k\in\textrm{Integers},\int_0^R \sqrt{r} \textrm{Abs}\left[\cos\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi r\right] dr\right]$$
and Mathematica gives the answer
$$\frac{2 S\left(\sqrt{2 k R+R}\right) \sec \left(\pi  k R+\frac{\pi  R}{2}\right)-2 \sqrt{2 k R+R} \tan \left(\pi  k R+\frac{\pi  R}{2}\right)}{\pi  (2 k+1)^{3/2} \sqrt{\sec ^2\left(\pi  k R+\frac{\pi  R}{2}\right)}}$$

and if you evaluate this function in $R=0.2$ and $k=1$ the result is $-0.0488018$.
This result is different from the definite integral with the same value for the parameters.
Thank you in advance again

Comment: Is this a mathematics question or a *Mathematica* question? If the former, move to another forum. If the latter, please paste actual *Mathematica* code.

Comment: there is a problem with the analytical result given by mathematica. No problem with mathematics. I was editing the formula before the negative vote

Comment: As to why you were asked for the *actual code*, it is easy to copy and paste the code from *Mathematica* into the question, and doing so makes it easy for those who would help you to copy from the question and paste into *Mathematica*.   Occasionally, there is the benefit of someone spotting an error in the code.  But mainly I would say that including code in questions like these is about being nice to those who would help you.

Comment: I tried but the the code was not readable

Comment: Hi, try copying the cell (Edit > Copy As... > InputText, although just plain copying often works).  In the SE edit window, paste it.  Select it.  Press the code button `{}` above the edit window.  Save edit.  *Do not try to convert it to TeX.*

Answer (score 1):

I get the same result from `NIntegrate` and `Integrate`.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[r] Cos[(k + 1/2) Pi r], {r, R, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> R > 0] /. {k -> 10, R -> 0.5}
NIntegrate[Sqrt[r] Cos[(10 + 1/2) Pi r], {r, 0.5, 1}]
```

> Output:
>
> 0.0459518
>
> 0.0459518

Answer (score 1):

I assume that |...| means `Abs[...]`.

Define the symbolic integral.

```
int[r0_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := Integrate[Sqrt[r] Abs[Cos[(k + 1/2) \[Pi] r]], {r, r0, 1}]
```

Define the numerical integral.

```
intN[r0_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[r] Abs[Cos[(k + 1/2) \[Pi] r]], {r, r0, 1}]
```

Compare these integrals for your chosen parameter values, using `1/2` rather than `0.5` to force symbolic evaluation in `int[1/2, 10]`.

```
{intN[##], {N[#], #} &@int[##]} &[1/2, 10]

(* {0.269865, 
  {0.269865,
  (1/(441 \[Pi]))(21 + 12 Sqrt[35] + 4 Sqrt[231] + 4 Sqrt[273] + 
  4 Sqrt[357] + 4 Sqrt[399] - 2 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[21/2]] + 
  4 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[11]] - 4 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[13]] + 
  4 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[15]] - 4 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[17]] + 
  4 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[19]] - 2 Sqrt[21] FresnelS[Sqrt[21]])}} *)
```

The results are numerically the same, and you've got a symbolic expression to use as well.

Comment: I agree but please read my redit question