# Interpolating an Antiderivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, interpolation, warning-messages

I'd like to be able to make `InterpolatingFunction`s for antiderivatives of functions that can't be integrated symbolically. However, the following code returns several error messages:

```
FunctionInterpolation[Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Here are the messages:

> Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {-1.25,-0.416667,0.416667,1.25}^{} cannot be combined. "
>
> Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {0.223144 +3.14159\ I,-0.875469+3.14159\ I,-0.875469,0.223144}\ {}\n cannot be combined. "
>
> Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {-1.25,-0.416667,0.416667,1.25}\ {} cannot be combined."
>
> General::stop: "Further output of Thread::tlden will be suppressed during this calculation."
>
> FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near t = 1.25`, the function did not evaluate to a real number.
>
> FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near t = 1.3277777777777777`, the function did not evaluate to a real number.

What's going on? Is there a simple way to make this work? Changing `Integrate` to `NIntegrate` doesn't help, though the error messages are different:

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> General::stop: "Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation. "

Comment: your example is indeed integrated by MMA without problems an gives: (t^3)^(1/3)*Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/3, 4/3, -t^3].

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes, it has no problems with the indefinite integral. The issue seems to be how I combined it with FunctionInterpolation. Strangely, other functions with more elementary integrals, e.g. Sqrt[1+x^2], do not produce any errors.

Comment: (at)Jim: no, it's the definite integral. The indefinte integral is the true antiderivative, and it looks different. But, please have a look at my solution which shows (a) that in a (natural) 2-step procedure there are no problems with calculating the interpolation of your definite integral, and (b) this definite integral is different from the antiderivative.

Comment: @JimBelk, This morning when I try first example, `FunctionInterpolation[Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, 10}]` does not give the errors you indicate, but `FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate@Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, 10}]` does give them.  (The reason has to do with the `ConditionalExpression` returned when the `Integrate` is evaluated without assumptions or a definite value for `t`.)  But can you confirm the same behavior?  If not, what version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: (at) Michael E2: you might wish to look at my solution for Version 8: No problems encountered in interpolating both the definite integral (Jim's) and the antiderivative.

Comment: FWIW, here's a closed form one can use if one is not afraid of elliptic integrals: $$f(x)=\frac{2x}{5}\sqrt{x^3+1}+\frac{\sqrt[4]{27}}{5}\mathrm{cn}^{(-1)} \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{x+\sqrt{3}+1}-1\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$$                 However, since $f(-1)=0$, to get something similar to the answers below, use the function $f(x)-f(0)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
antiD = NDSolveValue[{f'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x^3], f[0] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Example usage:

```
Plot[antiD[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

***Alternatively...***

This works because this function can be antidifferentiated (by *Mathematica*).

```
antiD = FunctionInterpolation[
 Evaluate @ Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> 0 < t < 10],
 {t, 0, 10}]
```

***or...***

```
integral[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}];
FunctionInterpolation[integral[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

`FunctionInterpolation` evaluated its argument on a symbolic `t`.  The pattern test `?NumericQ` prevents evaluation of `NIntegrate` until an actual number is substituted for `t`.  See also [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).  Note also that this way does many evaluations of `NIntegrate`, whereas the `NDSolve` method does just one integration.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Why doesn't the `NIntegrate` form do the right thing (by substituting the appropriate numerical value for $t?$)

Comment: @IgorRivin I was adding that, but the OP didn't actually ask that Q.  He asked about `Integrate`, and how to achieve his objective, which last Q I did answer.  The first Q is probably not worth going into very deeply.  `Evaluate` gets rid of the problem.

Comment: Ah, ok, fair enough. This is a bit of a subtle point...

Comment: @IgorRivin  Yes, I suppose it is...

Comment: Thanks! The NDSolve suggestion is cleaner than any other option (and is certainly what I will use), but I'm glad you also addressed what went wrong originally.

Comment: @JimBelk You're welcome.  `NDSolve` is very useful this way.  It's one of my favorites.  I've found `FunctionInterpolation` doesn't always give a highly accurate approximation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice answer. I followed the link link to your answer at the pitfalls question. I haven't visited it for a long time. To my amusement I saw that the question has 178 favorites! But the really unusual thing is that it has been favourited more than upvoted :)

Comment: When I need to generate accurate interpolation of a function I usually use Plot or Legacy'Plot for generating the points for Interpolation. FunctionInterpolation does not make adaptive refinement.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That's a good point and I have done that, too. But `NDSolve` has `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`.  I don't believe `Plot` has such controls (correct me, if I'm wrong -- I know it has [`"Refinement"` and so forth](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348), but it's a different way to control).  The above and `ifn = NDSolve[{y[t] == f[x[t]], x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]` are a pretty simple commands, and they tend to be the way I've done things the last few years.

Comment: Does NDSolve make adaptive refinement or it just decreases the step size when higher precision is requested?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It adapts step size according to error estimates. The estimates can be fooled (a little), so it's not perfect. `NDSolve` sampling can be quite different from `Plot`.  For instance `NDSolveValue[{y[t] == Sin[x[t]], x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` produces an interpolation with a max error of `6*10^-8` with 162 sample points whereas interpolating the `Line` produced by the corresponding `Plot` has a max error of `4*10^-6` with 431 sample points. But I don't want to exaggerate the differences; they're rather comparable, imo.

Answer (score 4):

There are two aspects in this problem depending on the exact definition of the task, and, as we shall see, both are completely solved by MMA without any additional facility.

The aspects are

a) calculate the interpolation of the definite integral $f=\int_0^t \sqrt{1+x^3} \, dx$

b) calculate the interpolation of the antiderivative $fad=\int\sqrt{1+x^3} \, dx$

**Part a) interpolation of Jim's definite integral**

There are no problems in interpolating your **definite integral** if you do it in two steps.

Step 1:

Calculate the definite integral (Mathematica does this exactly)

```
f = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t >= -1]

(* -> (t^3)^(1/3) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/3, 4/3, -t^3] *)
```

Step 2:

Do the interpolation

```
fi = FunctionInterpolation[f, {t, 0, 10}]

(* -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,10.`}},"<>"] *)
```

And finally check the equality of f and fi:

```
Plot[{f, fi[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]

(* skip the picture *)
```

For completeness:

```
$Version

(* -> "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)" *)
```

This procedure works fine also with many other functions, e.g. integer powers other than 3 under the sqrt.

**Part b) interpolation of the antiderivative**

The antiderivative is given by the **indefinite integral** :

```
fad = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^3], x]
```

$\frac{2 \left(x+x^4+(-1)^{1/6} 3^{3/4} \sqrt{-(-1)^{1/6} \left((-1)^{2/3}+x\right)} \sqrt{1+(-1)^{1/3} x+(-1)^{2/3} x^2} \text{EllipticF}\left[\text{ArcSin}\left[\frac{\sqrt{-(-1)^{5/6} (1+x)}}{3^{1/4}}\right],(-1)^{1/3}\right]\right)}{5 \sqrt{1+x^3}}$

This quantity, besides having a small imaginary part

```
fad /. x -> 1.25

(* -> 2.34276 - 1.17815*10^-16 I *)
```

has a dicontinuity in both Re and Im:

```
Plot[{Re[fad], Im[fad]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 5}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Re and Im of the antiderivative fad of \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(1 + \
x^3\)]\)", AxesLabel -> {"x", "Re/Im[fad]"}]
```

[image]

Discontinuities of antiderivatives are quite common, and they have been discussed in this community several times (cf. for example [Mismatch between numerical and analytic evaluation of an integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56957/mismatch-between-numerical-and-analytic-evaluation-of-an-integral/57704#57704))

This could potentially cause a problem for FunctionInterpolate over an interval including the jump.

But it is not the case here !

Rather, the interpolation returns the correct complex valued function, with just announcing - as it should do - an accuracy problem connected with the jump:

```
fadi = FunctionInterpolation[fad, {x, 0, 5}]
```

FunctionInterpolation::ncvb: FunctionInterpolation failed to meet the prescribed accuracy and precision goals after 6 recursive bisections near x = {1.99219}. Continuing to refine elsewhere. >>

```
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"] *)
```

Visualizing both Re and Im of the interpolation

```
Plot[{Re[fadi[t]], Im[fadi[t]]}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 5}, PlotLabel -> 
  "Re and Im of the interpolation of the \nantiderivative fadi of \\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(1 + x^3\)]\)", AxesLabel -> {"x", "Re/Im[fadi]"}]
```

[image]

It shows agreement with the original function except, as expected, in the vicinity of the jumps.

Summarizing part b)

the interpolation of the true antiderivative is done perfectly well by Mathematica with only a justified accuracy error message due to the jump.

**Conclusion**

I have checked the complete code with a fresh kernel and can state that no problems are encountered in version 8 for both interpretations of the problem.

Best regards,
Wolfgang