# How do I perform the following numerical integration

Tags: programming, numerical-integration, simulation

I have the following integral to evaluate numerically:
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{f(t)}\int_0^{t_b} t^m (t + n)^o \sin(pt) \mathrm{d}t \quad m,n,o,p \in \mathbb{R}$$

```
x[t]== f[t]^-1 Integrate[t^m*(t + n)^o*Sin[p t], {t, 0, tb}]
```

$t_b, m, n, o,$ and $p$ are known constants. I'm quite confident that it is straightforward to employ NIntegrate to solve [and plot] x(t) if it lacks $\frac{1}{f(t)}$ but I'm unsure about how to go about evulating the above integral and then generating plots. Any advice on the same would be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem... 1/f(t) is not inside the integral (?)

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem.

Comment: Well, if it's not inside the integral, you can just simply use NIntegrate[t^m*(t + n)^o*Sin[p t], {t, 0, tb}] and get a number.

Comment: I need the entire expression on the RHS to be evaluated at every time step, however. I've done a poor job of asking the question in retrospect, I guess. But hopefully that helps clarify my issue. So, basically, I need a list of values for x[t] so that I can plot that and see how x varies with t.

Comment: a little more about what it is I'm trying to do. I have solved an exact ode and plotted some behaviour for $x$. I have then proceeded to solve for $x$ through some approximation and finally obtained the above expression. But now I need to evaluate the expression at discrete instants so that I can plot $x$ and compare the analytical result from approximation to the simulated result.

Comment: Do `m` and `o` happen to be integers? Positive integers?  (Btw, the use of `o` as a parameter is a rather bad choice: so easily confused with zero.)

Comment: I would assume the function you want is $x(t_b) = \frac{1}{f(t_b)}\int_0^{t_b} t^m (t + n)^o \sin(pt) \;dt$, since the integral is not a function of $t$ -- is that correct?  (The confusing part is the use of the dummy variable $t$ inside the integral and as a free variable in the definition of $x(t)$.)

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59891/interpolating-an-antiderivative) shows how to numerically approximate an integral as a function of the end point. Do the answers to it solve your problem?  It seems fundamentally the same question.

Comment: @Michael E2  sorry. Yes. You're right. That's what the equation is. I'll check out the link you posted. Thanks.