# How to obtain adaptive sampling as in Plot function?

Tags: plotting, sampling

Adaptive sampling in `Plot` function can capture the oscillation of a function with very few points. How can I get a similar sequence of point pairs without using `Plot`. You can somehow dig into Graphic object to get the points as following:

```
In[1]:= Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6*Pi}, PlotPoints -> 2][[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]

Out[1]= {{0.0000188496, 0.0000188496}, {0.294543, 
  0.290302}, {0.589066, 0.555585}, {0.88359, 0.773021}, {1.17811, 
  0.923886}, {1.47264, 0.995186}, {1.76716, 0.980782}, {2.06168, 
  0.881914}, {2.35621, 0.707097}, {2.65073, 0.471385}, {2.94526, 
  0.195078}, {3.23978, -0.0980295}, {3.5343, -0.382694}, {3.82883, \
-0.634402}, {4.12335, -0.831476}, {4.41787, -0.956943}, {4.7124, \
-1.}, {5.00692, -0.956938}, {5.30145, -0.831465}, {5.59597, \
-0.634387}, {5.89049, -0.382677}, {6.18502, -0.0980107}, {6.47954, 
  0.195096}, {6.77406, 0.471401}, {7.06859, 0.70711}, {7.36311, 
  0.881923}, {7.65764, 0.980786}, {7.95216, 0.995184}, {8.24668, 
  0.923879}, {8.54121, 0.773009}, {8.83573, 0.555569}, {9.13025, 
  0.290284}, {9.42478, 
  3.67394*10^-16}, {9.7193, -0.290284}, {10.0138, -0.555569}, \
{10.3083, -0.773009}, {10.6029, -0.923879}, {10.8974, -0.995184}, \
{11.1919, -0.980786}, {11.4864, -0.881923}, {11.781, -0.70711}, \
{12.0755, -0.471401}, {12.37, -0.195096}, {12.6645, 
  0.0980107}, {12.9591, 0.382677}, {13.2536, 0.634387}, {13.5481, 
  0.831465}, {13.8426, 0.956938}, {14.1372, 1.}, {14.4317, 
  0.956943}, {14.7262, 0.831476}, {15.0207, 0.634402}, {15.3153, 
  0.382694}, {15.6098, 
  0.0980295}, {15.9043, -0.195078}, {16.1988, -0.471385}, {16.4933, \
-0.707097}, {16.7879, -0.881914}, {17.0824, -0.980782}, {17.3769, \
-0.995186}, {17.6714, -0.923886}, {17.966, -0.773021}, {18.2605, \
-0.555585}, {18.555, -0.290302}, {18.8495, -0.0000188496}}
```

I think there should be a formal way to do this. I searched `adaptive sampling` in the documents, nothing interesting pops out.

### Conclusions

@Michael E2 provides [an extensive answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85103/11867) for this question and similar questions. The ultimate solution for this problem is `FunctionInterpolation`, which can adjust accuracy of the result by changing `PrecisionGoal` and  `AccuracyGoal`. The option `MaxRecursion` should be added, if high accuracy result is needed. It should also be noted `MaxRecursion` in this function does not has the limit of 15 as in `Plot` function.

Meanwhile, the solution in [Transform an InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/transform-an-interpolatingfunction/67642#67642) is another very interesting way to solve this problem as well.

If the adaptive sampling in `Plot` function is needed, take the code from @george2079's answer.

**Please do read [@Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85103/11867) before you decide which function you should use.**

Comment: The key is what goal is guiding the adapting.  With `Plot`, it is the angle between consecutive line segments of the plot, which is entirely local.  With `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve`, it is the estimated error in the result; `NIntegrate` has both global and local adaptive strategies.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why do you always know the internal implementation of those functions?

Comment: Aw, shucks.  I've used it for 25 years, read the docs, attended conferences, read/participated on this site.  Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59892 and its comments; http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67642

Comment: @MichaelE2 You have an excellent memory. *Mathematica* is such a large system, I can barely remember even a part of these details. Well done!

Comment: To make it concrete, the key options that guide the adaptive sampling of `Plot[]` are `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, and (now hidden) `MaxBend`, which is the angle being talked about by @Michael.

Comment: Some references: [`MaxBend`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MaxBend) mentioned by @Guess. What I was really poking the OP about was whether there was some sort of specific goal in mind.  I could imagine something like `sample[f, errornorm, tolerance]`, where the function `errornorm` measures the error of a particular sampling.  But I can't imagine anything other than plotting and integration at this point.

Comment: In fact, one neat trick for numerically evaluating an integral in *Mathematica* is to let `Plot[]` do the adaptive sampling and then use the output for the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Here is why I am interesting in this problem. I am using a software, which require me to input a tabular data for calculation. Then the software will use the given value and do linear interpolation for its own calculation. What I want to do is to use minimum points of input to get a good approximation of the original function. This is why I am thinking about the adaptive sampling in `Plot` function.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I think you are right. And this is why I am not so sure about george2079's trick mentioned in the answer which can force *Mathematica* to evaluate trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @Kattern According to the "Conclusions" section in your question Michail's answer provides the best solution for your problem. Why isn't it Accepted then?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Michail's answer is better for the general question, but george2079's answer provides the answer of the question. I think it may be misleading  for those who are just interesting in the answer of the question, not the general problem behind it. If this is not a problem, I am very happy to choose Michail's answer.

Comment: @Kattern In general the user [is expected](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to accept the best answer from his own point of view while the community determines the ratings of the answers by voting. This model of "separation of powers" isn't perfect: for example the Accepted answer has more chances to be upvoted than others, so actually the user promotes the answer by Accepting it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*[Edit notice: I discovered a workaround to make the options `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` work.]*

#### `FunctionInterpolation`

I have had a prejudice against [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html). It does not really seem fully implemented.  I've even asked people at Wolfram, who didn't seem to use it and even recommended using `NDSolve`.  But it does do adaptive sampling.  It takes `PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal`, `MaxRecursion` and `InterpolationOrder` options, as well as a few others.  None are mentioned in the documentation, but one can find them with `Options`:

```
Options[FunctionInterpolation]
(*
  {InterpolationOrder -> 3, InterpolationPrecision -> Automatic, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
   InterpolationPoints -> 11, MaxRecursion -> 6}
*)
```

I'm not sure what `InterpolationPrecision` does; it does not seem to be the same as `WorkingPrecision` in other numerical solvers.  The option `InterpolationPoints` controls the initial sampling; I say controls, because the actual initial sampling is not always the same.  (For instance, when set to `11`, `12`, or `13`, the initial sampling consists of 13 points in each case.)

Using the `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` with any settings other than `Automatic` results in **errors, when the domain is given in terms of exact numbers**.  If the domain is given in terms of approximate real numbers (machine or arbitrary precision), then the options and `FunctionInterpolation` work.  The default settings for `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` appear to be `6` or thereabouts.  More importantly, it adapts its sampling to the `InterpolationOrder` and seems to do its job in meeting the precision+accuracy goal.  (The goal is that the absolute error be less than `10^-acc + 10^-prec * Abs[f[x]]`.)

You can get the points from an `InterpolatingFunction` like this:

```
points = Transpose[{Flatten[if["Grid"]], if["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
```

*Linear interpolation.*

In all the examples, the gold curve shows the precision+accuracy goal.  When the blue plot is below it, the precision+accuracy goal is met.

An objective function that oscillates increasingly rapidly:

```
obj[x_] = 10 + Sin[x^2]
if = FunctionInterpolation[obj[x], {x, 0., 10.}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1];
"Points" -> Length[if["Grid"]]
With[{prec = 6, acc = 6},
 LogPlot[   (* error plot *)
  Evaluate[Flatten[{Abs[if[x] - obj[x]], 10^-acc + 10^-prec*Abs[obj[x]]}]],
  {x, 0., 10.}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
 ]

(*  "Points" -> 11634  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An objective function that grows larger:

```
obj[x_] = Exp[x + Sin[4 x]];
if = FunctionInterpolation[obj[x], {x, 0., 10.}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1];
"Points" -> Length[if["Grid"]]
With[{prec = 6, acc = 6},
 LogPlot[   (* error plot *)
  Evaluate[Flatten[{Abs[if[x] - obj[x]], 10^-acc + 10^-prec*Abs[obj[x]]}]],
  {x, 0., 10.}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
 ]

(*  "Points" -> 17603  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first example with `PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4`:

```
obj[x_] = 10 + Sin[x^2]
With[{prec = 4, acc = 4}, 
 if = FunctionInterpolation[obj[x], {x, 0., 10.}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> prec, AccuracyGoal -> acc];
 Print["Points" -> Length[if["Grid"]]];
 LogPlot[   (* error plot *)
  Evaluate[Flatten[{Abs[if[x] - obj[x]], 10^-acc + 10^-prec*Abs[obj[x]]}]],
  {x, 0., 10.}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
 ]
(*  Points->1191  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Cubic interpolation.*

`InterpolationOrder -> 3` is the default:

```
obj[x_] = 10 + Sin[x^2]
if = FunctionInterpolation[obj[x], {x, 0., 10.}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3];  
"Points" -> Length[if["Grid"]]
With[{prec = 6, acc = 6},
 LogPlot[   (* error plot *)
  Evaluate[Flatten[{Abs[if[x] - obj[x]], 10^-acc + 10^-prec*Abs[obj[x]]}]],
  {x, 0., 10.}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
 ]

(*  "Points" -> 856  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Other choices - Summary

<s>A main advantage to these over `FunctionInterpolation` is being able to change the precision/accuracy goals of the interpolation.</s> To me, there now seems no great advantage to the methods below; indeed, the interpolation produced by `FunctionInterpolation` seems excellent -- I'll have to rethink my prejudice.  `FunctionInterpolation` is a bit slow by comparison with `Plot` and `NDSolve`.  On the other hand, `FunctionInterpolation` allows higher settings of `MaxRecursion`, whereas in `Plot`, it is limited to `15` -- okay, not a severe restriction probably.  Overall, I would say `FunctionInterpolation` is superior to the methods below.

**Plot** -- Precision control is a little tricky, but can be adequately managed with `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, and `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> bound}}` (`MaxBend` is now deprecated), where `bound` is a bound on the angle in radians (see e.g. [How does Plot work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/how-does-plot-work/29348#29348)).  `Plot` tends to oversample unnecessarily in some neighborhoods with high settings of `MaxRecursion`, sampling well beyond the meeting the maximum bend bound between line segments.  `FunctionInterpolation` produces fewer sample points meeting the precision and accuracy goal of `6`.

**NDSolve** -- Good precision control. Usually reasonably fast. Seems to produce fewer sample points than `Plot`, more than `FunctionInterpolation`. See my answer, [Transform an InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/transform-an-interpolatingfunction/67642#67642), for two basic methods for interpolating a function with `NDSolve`.

**NIntegrate** -- Worst.  I can't really imagine recommending it in any situation, unless the interpolation is to be integrated.  While you can control the precision of the resulting integral, the precision of an interpolation is different (except when integrating it). The option setting `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "RombergQuadrature" -> False}}` is the best you can do for approximating linear interpolation (that I found).  Sometimes it manages to get good precision and sampling efficiency.  It usually is much slower than any other method, and for what you get, it hardly seems worth it.

**Manual global recursive subdivision** -- Not too hard to code.  If the function tamely oscillates, you can get good control over precision and good sampling efficiency.

**Manual local adaptive step-size iteration** -- By which I mean, choosing a step size at each step to meet the precision/accuracy goals (for linear interpolation, the error estimate is based on the second derivative).  For tame functions, this can produce the best sampling faster than the other methods.

FWIW, I have code and data to back this up.  Just ask.  I've toyed with this problem on and off in my spare time over the last few weeks.  It seems to come up in one way or another every now then on this site.  What I have, though, has ballooned to the point that I'm embarrassed.

Comment: A really cool answer, takes time to read. I am curious how can I get the method of `InterpolatingFunction`, like `["Grid"]` in `Transpose[{Flatten[if["Grid"]], if["ValuesOnGrid"]}]`. I do not find them in the documents.

Comment: @kattern Thanks!  Here are some references on `InterpolatingFunction`: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html#120436095,
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction

Comment: The answer is a bit confusing about whether the `FunctionInterpolation` can control the precision/accuracy goals. With a little test, I think `Using the precision and accuracy options results in errors, so they're useless.` seems accurate.

Comment: @kattern Thanks for your comment.  For whatever reason, it made me think to try something that hadn't occurred to me.  I seem to have found a way to make `FunctionInterpolation` work properly with the options.  So you now can set the precision/accuracy goals and get an interpolation that is that precise/accurate (as defined in *Mathematica*). Let me know if you have trouble.

Comment: Additional information on undocumented syntax of `FunctionInterpolation` can be found in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12564556/590388).

Answer (score 21):

I know you said "without plot", but why reinvent the wheel?

```
  adaptivepoints=Sort@Last@Last@
        Reap[Plot[f = Sin[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
             EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{f, x}]]];
```

You can similarly use `NIntegrate`, which might be more robust in terms of warning you if the adaptive scheme is not converging.

```
   g[x_?NumericQ] := Sin[x];     
   Sort@Last@Last@Reap@
        NIntegrate[f = g[x], {x, 0, 1000}, 
            EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f}]];
```

note for `NIntegrate` you should force numeric evaluation, otherwise it might employ some quadrature scheme that minimizes the number of eval points.

Comment: OK, that seems a solution.

Comment: Why is `NIntegrate` more robust? It looks like  they both controlled by `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: `NIntegrate` is (much) more robust in the criteria it uses to confirm convergence.  `Plot` just looks for the result to be smooth, `NIntegate` looks for successive recursions of the integral to converge.

Comment: Thanks to share the trick on disable quadrature in `NIntegrate`. Theoretically, you also can do quadrature on numeric functions, how does this trick work?

Comment: @Kattern The trick is making the objective function to look as "black box" for `NIntegrate` in order to disable symbolic processing which `NIntegrate` performs by default.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov for quadrature scheme, I think it only requires the function can be evaluated at every points. Therefore, I think the correct way to disable quadrature may be   `Method ->"TrapezoidalRule"`.

Comment: @Kattern From the symbolic form of the integrand `NIntegrate` [can detect](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntroduction.html#266479739) some its features like periodicity in order to minimize the number of evaluation points. AFAIK it will apply symbolic until you switch it off with `Method->{Automatic, "SymbolicPreprocessing"->None}` (instead of `Automatic` may be explicit method specification) or by using the "black box" method (`_?NumericQ`). Both ways do not disable the quadrature scheme.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks! I think your explanation is more accurate. Unless you explicitly tell `NIntegrate` not to use quadrature scheme, a reasonable choice for *Mathematica* is to always use quadrature scheme in the process. The difference is on the symbolic preprocessing.

Comment: +1, It is first time for me to use `NIntegrate` to sampling point.BTW, `ListLinePlot[adaptivepoints]` cannot draw the graph.

Comment: Minor typo: Alexey meant to say `SymbolicProcessing` rather than `SymbolicPreprocessing` above.

Comment: The `AbsArgPlot` function (new in Mathematica 12) is documented to have a "adaptive algorithm to choose additional sample points, subdividing a given interval at most MaxRecursion times".  By replacing the `Plot` in this answer with it you apparently get an alternative solution.