# Why is my Plot3D not smooth?

Tags: plotting

Unless I'm missing something very obvious, why does this code:

```
Plot3D[r^(-2) + 1000*r^2 + 10*Cos[x],{r,0.01,0.5},{x,0,20*Pi},PlotRange->{0,200}]
```

generate this plot:
[image]

Why is it not a smooth plot?

(Mathematica version 10.1.0.0, Linux x86-64.)

Comment: Both Mathematica 10.4 and 11.0 on OS X yield a smooth surface

Comment: If all else fails I'll try upgrading, but is there a mathematica option to ask it to smooth this out.

Comment: Look at the options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`

Comment: Have you tried this with a fresh kernel?

Comment: try `PlotPoints -> 100` or `MaxRecursion -> 10`

Comment: I think you mistyped the function in your code. I can reproduce your image with `Cos[10 * x]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uu6aM.png  -- Try adding the option `PlotPoints -> {25, 75}`

Comment: @Sascha: really? My friends 10.4 version on windows reproduces my error. And yes, problem persists on a new kernel (unfortunately). Even on a different machine I have (which runs version 10.0 I think).

Comment: @MichaelE2: Ah thanks. They seem to smooth it out. `PlotPoints` seems less intensive than `MaxRecursion`. And yes I did have a typo. Thanks! I should have had the range of x to be [0,20pi] but effectively the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @vito: Thanks! I get a smooth plot as I expect with those options added. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `MaxRecursion` helps with local smoothing, but when it's needed everywhere, it can be expensive. OTOH, when it's needed in a small area, it will be more efficient than increasing `PlotPoints`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The documentation on `MaxRecursion` especially is a little sparse. If you'd like to flesh out what you said here into an answer it would be interesting to me and might be useful for others... (if you have the time :)

Comment: @Zorawar There's some explanation here: [(19121)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19121), [(29346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346). Also somewhat related: [(82912)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82912)

Comment: @MichaelE2: Ah, those look very interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Zorawar Try this, Plot3D[1/r^2 + 1000 r^2 + 10 Cos[x], {r, 0.01, 0.5}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 200}]