# Refine `Plot` around y=1 only

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I have a complicated function $f$ which turns an input (let's say a single number, to simplify) into  either 1, -1, -2 or -3, each value corresponding to different categories.

I can plot the categories as a function of the input, and that's a typical results:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**What I am interested in is $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.** For example, for the plot above it would be something like $[-11.1,-10.9]\cup [-9.7,7.6]\cup[-7.4,-0.5]\cup\dots$, but much more accurately (typically, with five digits).

One possibility  would be to increase `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursions`, but this will also refine the parts in which I am not intersted, i.e. the transitions between -1 and -2, etc.

---

Here is a simplified example; `f` is a very simple function given in the end, but assume it is not known explicitly.

```
plot = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/5];
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The points can be extracted from the plot and the transitions obtained with BobHanlon's code:

```
transitions = Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]] //.
                  {s___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y1_}, e___} :> {s, {x1, y1}, e}

(* {{-5., -2.}, {-3.13482, 1.}, {0.0167145, -1.}, {3.14997, -2.}} *)
```

Since I'm interested in the $x$ values of image $1$, I simply select:

```
pos = Position[transitions, _?(Last[#] == 1 &), {1}];
Take[transitions[[All, 1]], Flatten@{pos, pos + 1}]

(* {-3.13482, 0.0167145} *)
```

Which gives me an estimation of $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ of $[-3.13482, 0.0167145]$.
 In the present case, `f` is build up so that the exact transitions are known: the solution is `-Pi,0`. My goal is to get more accurate values, in an efficient manner.

One possibility is to increase `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecusions`: for example, same code with `PlotPoints -> 2000, MaxRecursion -> 5`:

```
 plot = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
   ImageSize -> 700, PlotPoints -> 2000, MaxRecursion -> 5];
transitions = 
 Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, 
    Infinity][[1]] //. {s___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y1_}, 
    e___} :> {s, {x1, y1}, e}
pos = Position[transitions, _?(Last[#] == 1 &), {1}];
Take[transitions[[All, 1]], Flatten@{pos, pos + 1}]

(* {-3.14151, 0.0000912312} *)
```

It's much better... but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this, in particular without refining the transitions which are not of interest. In other words, focus on making very fine transitions *only* when the functions reaches or leaves the value 1.

I am also interested in approaches which are not plot-based; I just want to get the intervals of image 1 as accurate as possible.

---

Function `f` used in the illustration code:

```
f[x_] = -UnitStep[x - Pi] + 3 UnitStep[x + Pi] - 2 UnitStep[x] - 2;
```

Comment: For Mathematica v10.2 or later, convert your data into steps and use [`ListStepPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon What data? It's a "continuum". I used `UnitStep` as a _trivial_ example but in reality is a much more complicated function.

Comment: Knowing *how* `f` is defined might help. Is it always a linear combination of unit-step functions?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, actually it's really complicated: it takes a value $x$, makes a `List` from a list of interpolating functions evaluated at $x$, then applies another function to the list and check some criteria such as "does the function exceeds this value" or "is the derivative positive at x=3".

Answer (score 3):

`Plot` has an suboption `"ControlValue"` which specify the max angle between successive points (in Radians)

```
f[x_] := -UnitStep[x - Pi] + 3 UnitStep[x + Pi] - 2 UnitStep[x] - 2;
    gr = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5},
      Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> 2 Pi/100}}, 
      Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotPoints -> 10, 
      MeshStyle -> PointSize[0.015]]
```

[image]

```
intervals = Cases[Normal[gr], Point[___], {1, Infinity}] //
      First /@ # & //
     Sort //
    Split[#, Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.1 &] & //
   #[[All, {1, -1}, 1]] &;

intervals // Grid
```

[image]

error around -Pi :

```
-3.1415587451696543` - -3.141626562009932`
```

> 0.0000678168

There are a lot of related informations [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85103/5467) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348/5467)

Comment: Does not this refine _everywhere_ and not just around `y=1`? Which is precisely what I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] = -UnitStep[x - 2] + 3 UnitStep[2 x + 4] - 2 UnitStep[x] - 2;

transitions = 
 Cases[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None], Line[pts_] :> pts, 
    Infinity][[1]] //.
  {s___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y1_}, e___} :>
   {s, {x1, y1}, e}

(*  {{-5., -2.}, {-1.99783, 1.}, {0.000769648, -1.}, {2.00061, -2.}}  *)

ListStepPlot[transitions]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Transitions occur at discontinuities in function's derivative. Select transition pairs for which function has desired value between those transitions.

```
intervals[func_, val_: 1] :=
 Module[{x, transitions},
  transitions = 
   SortBy[x /. Solve[#, x][[1]] & /@ 
     Cases[func'[x], {Indeterminate, rel_} :> rel, Infinity], N[#] &];
  Select[
   Partition[transitions, 2, 1],
   func[Mean[#]] == val &]]

f[x_] = -UnitStep[x - 2] + 3 UnitStep[2 x + 4] - 2 UnitStep[x] - 2;

intervals[f]

(*  {{-2, 0}}  *)

f2[x_] = -UnitStep[x - Pi] + 3 UnitStep[x + Pi] - 2 UnitStep[x] - 2;

intervals[f2]

(*  {{-π, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: I don't think that answers my question: it does not seem to refine around the transitions to 1. As I understand, what you added (essentially `//.
  {s___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y1_}, e___} :>
   {s, {x1, y1}, e}`) extracts transitions (which I can do too, in a less elegant manner) but does not refine. Or am I missing something?

Comment: From your example, the reverse image of $\{1\}$ is $[-1.99783,0.000769648]$. I would like to refine it, in the sense that it should be closer to $[-2,0]$ (without using the properties of the trivial function `f`).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know them, "-2" and "0" are trivial transitions here, but actually they are numerical values which I am looking for with as many digits as possible (5 should be enough).

Comment: I just clarified (I hope!) the question.