# Speed up the "FourierCoefficient" of SPWM wave

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to view the Fourier coeffs of one SPWM *(1)* wave:

```
spwmWave[t_, refFreq_, index_, m_] :=  Abs[Sign[Abs[Sin[2 Pi refFreq t]*m] - Abs[TriangleWave[t refFreq index/2]]] + 1]/2 * SquareWave[t refFreq]

Plot[spwmWave[t, 50., 20, 0.8], {t, 0, 0.02}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000]  

FourierCoefficient[spwmWave[t, 50., 20, 0.8], t, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/(1/50.)}]
```

The "FourierCoefficient" function execute long, and longer with greater 'index' value. Any way to speed up it?

*(1)* SPWM stands for "Sinusoidal Pulse Witdth Modulation" (Electronics Engineering)
[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that your $x(t)$ i.e. spwmWave. is hard to integrate. btw, you can remove the first `Abs` and it does not affect the plot. Same plot is generated. So no need for that extra `Abs`

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a answer, but it can help :

When one rewrites `spwmWave[t, 50., 20, 0.8]` as a sum `Unitstep`like this :

```
    spwmWave01=
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0191104+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0188598+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0182131+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0177393+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0173001+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0166529+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0163639+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0156074+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.015397+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.014603+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0143929+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0136361+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0133473+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0127+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0122607+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.011787+t] +
 0.5 UnitStep[-0.0111401+t]-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0108897+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00911031+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00885966+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00821306+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00773909+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00730001+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00665274+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00636396+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00560728+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00539688+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00460304+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.0043927+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00363612+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00334723+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00269994+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00226079+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.00178718+t] +
-0.5 UnitStep[-0.00114019+t]+0.5 UnitStep[-0.000889589+t];  

 Plot[spwmWave01, {t, 0, 0.02}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

> [image]

Then
 `FourierCoefficient[spwmWave01, t, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/(1/50.)}]` is 20X faster than your inital `FourierCoefficient[spwmWave[t, 50., 20, 0.8], t, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/(1/50.)}]`

Comment: I don't have any nice solution to transform automatically your code in a sum of `UnitStep`

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130942/5467) but I have no time to investigate further at the moment