# NDSolveValue gives up without warning or solution on PDEtoODE system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, finite-difference-method, fluid-dynamics

I have the following pair of PDEs that I want to solve in the half-space x>=0: 
[image]
I followed [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270457/fourth-order-nonlinear-pde-depicting-dynamics-of-liquid-lenses) to decompose the 4th-order height equation into two 2nd-order ones to respect the hyperbolic conservation law and it solves beautifully. However, I would like to solve directly for the pressure `p = D[h,{x,2}]` (instead of placing it in `Block`) as I require 2nd-order spatial derivatives of it (ie 4th spatial derivative of `h`) for further computations. With my below code, `NDSolveValue` just exits without any warning. `sol` simply remains as the `NDSolveValue` call.
[image]

Providing an ic to `p` doesn't resolve the issue either.

1. Could it be because there are no time derivatives of `p` in `eqp`?

Of course, as an alternative, I can easily increase the `InterpolationOrder` of the solutions, but it would be interesting to solve directly for the curvature too.

Thank you so much!

Code: (`pdetoode` can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/88731))

```
ϵ = 0.1;
b = 0.1;
Ca = 10^-3;
Pe = 10^6;
α = 0.1;
σ[Γ_] := (α + 1)/(1 + (((α + 1)/α)^(1/3) - 1)*Γ)^3 - α
Hfunc[x_] := 1/2*(1 + Tanh[100*x])
hinit = (1 + b - x^2)*Hfunc[1 - x] + b*Hfunc[x - 1];
Γinit = Hfunc[1 - x];

uniform = Subdivide[30, 2000];
rb = uniform[[-1]];

With[{h = h[x, t], Γ = Γ[x, t], 
  p = p[x, t], qh = qh[x, t], q2 = q2[x, t]},
 eqp = p == D[h, {x, 2}];
 eqqh = qh == h^2/2*D[σ[Γ], x] + Ca*h^3/3*p;
 eqh = D[h, t] == -D[qh, x];
 eqΓ = D[Γ, t] == -D[Γ*h*D[σ[Γ], x] + Ca*(Γ*h^2)/2*p, x] + 1/Pe*D[Γ, {x, 2}];
 ic = {h == hinit, Γ == Γinit} /. t -> 0;
 bc = Flatten[{{D[h, x] == 0, D[h, {x, 3}] == 0, D[Γ, x] == 0} /. x -> 0, {D[h, x] == 0, D[h, {x, 3}] == 0, D[Γ, x] == 0} /. x -> rb}]; (*bc if I do not solve directly for pressure*)
 bcp = Flatten[{{D[h, x] == 0, D[p, x] == 0, D[Γ, x] == 0} /. x -> 0, {D[h, x] == 0, D[p, x] == 0, D[Γ, x] == 0} /. x -> rb}];
 ]

domain = {0, rb}
grid = uniform;
difforder = 2;
remove1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

tfunc = pdetoode[{h, Γ, p, qh}[x, t], t, grid, 
   difforder, False];
odemid = Block[{p}, Map[tfunc, {eqqh}, {2}]];
odep = tfunc@eqp // remove1;
odeh = Block[{qh}, Set @@@ odemid; tfunc@eqh] // remove1;
odeΓ = Block[{qh}, Set @@@ odemid; tfunc@eqΓ] // remove1;
ode = {odep, odeh, odeΓ};

odeic = tfunc@ic;
With[{sf = 1}, odebc = diffbc[t, sf]@bcp // tfunc];
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {p, h, Γ}, grid];

Monitor[sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], time];

{psol, hsol, csol} = rebuild[#, grid, 2] & /@ sol;

(*visualisation*)
Manipulate[
 Plot[{hsol[r, t], csol[r, t]}, {x, ##}, PlotPoints -> 100] & @@ domain, {t, 0, 1, 0.001}]
```

Expected output for `h` (blue) and `Γ` (red)
[image]

At the request of @Alex Trounev, here is working code to reproduce the above plot of h and Γ, the difference is only in the discretisation procedure:

```
remove2 = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
remove1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
tfunc = pdetoode[{h, Γ, p, qh}[x, t], t, grid, difforder, False];
odemid = Map[tfunc, {eqp, eqqh}, {2}];
odeh = Block[{p,qh}, Set @@@ odemid; tfunc@eqh] // remove2;
odeΓ = Block[{p,qh}, Set @@@ odemid; tfunc@eqΓ] // remove1;
ode = {odeh, odeΓ};

odeic = tfunc@ic;
With[{sf = 1}, odebc = diffbc[t, sf]@bc // tfunc];
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {h, Γ}, grid];

Monitor[sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}, EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], time];

{hsol, csol} = rebuild[#, grid, 2] & /@ sol;
```

**Update:**
Testing out the method proposed by @xzcd, I obtained the following solution for the pressure.
My question though, is why is the value so different compared to the one obtained from differentiating `hsol` directly? (`psol` is the new solution, `psoldif=D[hsol[x,t],{x,2}]` is the one from differentiation) Am I missing something?

```
Manipulate[Plot[psol[x, t], {x, 0, 10},PlotPoints -> 100], {t, 0, 5, 0.01}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[psoldif /. t -> a, {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100], {a, 0, 5, 0.0001}]
```

[image]

In response to my previous statement that it could be due to the error message I obtained during discretisation of the IC of `p`:`General::munfl: 4.9226*10^-155^2 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.` I doubt that it is the source of the issue because it occurs only far away from the initial "drop" deposited where the pressure is very very small.

**Update 2**
I was careless and did not plot the full PlotRange, thanks @xzczd for pointing that out. However, I noticed that the pressure solution (light blue) is greater than that rebuilt using `fdd` (red): why is this so?

[image]

Comment: Could you upload working code you used to plot picture above?

Comment: @AlexTrounev sorry for the delay, I have uploaded the code!

Comment: (-1) The update is careless.

Comment: @xzczd sorry what do you mean?

Comment: 1. Definition of `remove2` is missing. 2. The code text of the 2 `Manipulate[…]`s are not given. 3. The `General::munfl` is posted without any explanation. There may be more.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @xzczd. I have made edits; hope it is better. I also clarified the ```General::munfl``` error.

Comment: You should compare the 2 solutions at the same `PlotRange`, and the `PlotRange` should not be too small.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142024/discussion-between-ariana-fenris-and-xzczd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could it be because there are no time derivatives of `p` in `eqp`?

Yes. One of the weakness of DAE solver of `NDSolve` is, `"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"` never tries to differentiate the algebraic equation, it simply `Solve` it. When certain derivative term is missing, it returns the input silently. A simpler example illustrating the issue:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0, y[t] == 0, x[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
        Method -> "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"]
(* Input returned *)
```

↑ This fails because there's no explicit `y'[t]` term in the system. (To learn more about `"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"`, please read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871). )

By modifying definition of `ic` to

```
ic = {h == hinit, Γ == Γinit, p == D[hinit, x, x]} /. t -> 0;
```

and definition of `odep` to

```
odep = tfunc@D[eqp, t] // remove1;
```

and set

```
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}
(* Not necessary in principle, but "Solve" is too slow for large system *)
```

for `NDSolve`, the problem will be resolved. (Though not necessary, `uniform` can be reduced to e.g. `uniform = Subdivide[2, 500];` to save some time. )

However, it doesn't make much sense to "solve directly for the pressure `p`". Perhaps what's in your mind is something like:

[How to find a numerical antiderivative with NIntegrate methods?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/227869/1871)

↑ In this case the method makes a difference (to some degree) because we've turned to the adapative ODE solver to integrate, while in our case, no matter how you handle the `p == D[h, {x, 2}]`, the spatial derivative will be calculated by `fdd` (`` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``) as long as you're using `pdetoode`. If you just want to avoid differentiating the `InterpolatingFunction` of `h`, calculate `p` with

```
hlst = Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sol[[1]];
gridlst = {grid, Flatten[sol][[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]]};
psol = ListInterpolation[fdd[{2, 0}, gridlst, hlst, DifferenceOrder -> difforder], 
   gridlst];
```

is enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and for all the edits, I apologise for them)! Sorry for the delay, I tested it out but have a new question regarding the difference in the solutions output, could you take a look at that?