# Efficient ways to calculate a cumulative sums (integral) for Plotting

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, result-accumulation

I want to calculate cumulative integrals of the form
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x dt\ F(t)
$$
efficiently in Mathematica. $F(t)$ could be a simple function but also some random function that does not have a *primitive integral*.

```
tmax = 100;
f[x_] := NIntegrate[Sin[t], {t, 0, x}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, tmax}, PlotLabel -> "Solution to ODE (Smoothing)"]
```

**This takes a very long time to execute and I assume, that when it plots, the cumulative sum is calculated for each single *x*-value independently, while it could just store the result of the previous computation and add the new term to it. My question is: Is there a way to calculate the cumulative sum more efficiently here?**

An idea is to map the values of $F(t)$ on some choosen $x$-values values and then use Mathematica's `Accumulate` function. But that becomes cumbersome as soon as several nested integrals are involved(e.g. the cumulative sum of the cumulative sum...).
That is why, I hope, that you have better ideas.

Comment: Over a finite interval, `f = NDSolve[{y'[x] == F[x], y[a] == 0}, y, {x, a, b}]`, where `a` and `b` are given numeric values, can't be beat, I don't think.   You can plot it with `LineLinePlot[f]` or `Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59892/4999