# Strange results from evaluating a simple integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I am trying to do a seemingly simple integral in Mathematica 10 and am getting strange results:

```
g[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] = -Log[Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2]]
Integrate[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0.1, 0.1], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

I am getting back

```
3.0725 - 1.16032 I
```

Clearly this is nonsense, since the integrand is real everywhere, and the integration doesn't go anywhere near to $g$'s singularity. What gives?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76393/real-integral-giving-imaginary-answer

Comment: Making those `.1's` into `1/10` results in `0` ( very fast.. ) (v9.)

Comment: Yes, I get that too, and it agrees with some very simple Riemann sum code I hand-wrote. I'm still curious why both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` choke on this simple integral (and how to avoid this bug in the future).

Comment: (1) It's not strictly true that the integrand is real **everywhere**. E.g., `g[Cos[1], Sin[1], 1. I, 1. I]`. Clearly *M* is using complex methods to evaluate the integral, and the approximate coefficients can cause numerical error in the symbolic analysis. It could also be a bug. (2) In V10.1, I get `-9.58041*10^-8 + 1.88738*10^-15 I`, which is effectively a real result and numerically close-ish to the true answer. (3) Adding the assumption that θ is real produces `12.29 - 4.44089*10^-16 I`, closer to real, farther from the true answer. A similar answer if ``0.1`16`` is used instead of `0.1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 (1) True but 0.1 is hard-coded as the third and fourth argument; h[t] = g[Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.1, 0.1] is real for all real t.

Comment: @user168715 I should have used `t = 1 + I`, then, and left the `0.1`.  Sorry about that.  Clearly, *M* is **not** assuming theta is real, nor does it have to be.  (It is clear because adding the assumption that it is real changes the result.)  BTW, which subversion are you using?  As I said, I don't get the same result as you on 10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that `Integrate` can do some strange things with your function `g`. From plotting `g`, we can see the integral should clearly be zero.

```
g[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] = -Log[Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2]]
Plot[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 1/10, 1/10], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: plot]

Further,

```
Integrate[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 1/10, 1/10], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

gives zero as expected, but

```
Integrate[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0.1, 0.1], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

gives

> ```
> -9.58041*10^-8 + 1.88738*10^-15 I
> ```

which may be due to errors resulting from the use of inexact arithmetic. However, I can not explain the following:

```
Integrate[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0.1, 0.1], {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> θ ∈ Reals]
```

> Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
>
> ```
> 12.29 - 4.44089*10^-16 I
> ```

I carried out these calculations in V10.1.0.

#### Update

I reported the strange result from evaluating

```
Integrate[g[Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0.1, 0.1], {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> θ ∈ Reals]
```

to Wolfram tech support. The response was

> It does appear that Integrate is not behaving properly in this case and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided.

Therefore, I marking this question with the [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) tag.

Comment: Thanks; I am using 10.0 which explains the difference in our answers. I'm confused why the `Assumptions` makes any difference, though -- shouldn't Mathematica conclude that $\theta$ is real from the fact that it is sampled from the interval $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: @user168715. I don't blame you for being puzzled by the result returned when the `Assumptions` option is given; I am puzzled by it too. I am going to report it to Wolfram Research tech support. If I get a useful reply, I will update this answer to convey to the _Mathematica_.SE community.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to feed approximate numbers like 0.1 to symbolic methods.

Have a look at the indefinite integral `Integrate[g[Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], x2, y2], \[Theta]]` to see what's going on. Mathematica has to go very far into complex analysis to solve this integral symbolically. I suspect the several terms with branch points at `\[Theta] == \[Pi]` are particularly treacherous. I'm not surprised that Mathematica cannot find its way back onto the real line when you also ask it to deal with approximate rather than exact numbers.